# Google Map iframe not loading correctly in bootstrap3 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am using google map embeded api to display direction between two points.

```
<p><iframe width='600' height='450' frameborder='0' style='border:0' src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyAb9sz-Ih7YtVpdvoT5mLqgkJBx99yR8bc&origin=Anand,+Gujarat,+India&destination=Ahmedabad,+Gujarat,+India&mode=driving'></iframe></p>
```

This works fine every time in html file.

But when I place it in bootstrap3 modal body, it worked only once and now its not showing correct map, instead it shows whole world map.

I have to zoom to view actual directions.

Below is bootstrap code for same.

```
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-cancel"></i></a>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><iframe width='600' height='450' frameborder='0' style='border:0' src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyAb9sz-Ih7YtVpdvoT5mLqgkJBx99yR8bc&origin=Anand,+Gujarat,+India&destination=Ahmedabad,+Gujarat,+India&mode=driving'></iframe></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
    <!-- javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- These are all the javascript files -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/color-picker.js"></script>   
</body>

</html>
```

Unable to figure out What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

the code is working fine.. try deleting your cache in the browser and try again..

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-cancel"></i></a>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><iframe width='600' height='450' frameborder='0' style='border:0' src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyAb9sz-Ih7YtVpdvoT5mLqgkJBx99yR8bc&origin=Anand,+Gujarat,+India&destination=Ahmedabad,+Gujarat,+India&mode=driving'></iframe></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alaskaz1864/VpTR3/

Comment: Its not, even this fiddle is not working on my system, tried to clear cache and reload, also opening it it incognito window, its shows same world map. Can you please refresh results, as it worked for first time in my case too. After wards its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same exact problem.

After scouring the internet for hours (days, possibly) I finally wrote a custom modal dialog strictly for my map's display:

HTML

```
                <div id="viewmap" class="modalDialog">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#calendar" runat="server" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                        <h4>Map to <%: evnt.VenueName %></h4>
                        <iframe
                          width="100%"
                          height="450"
                          frameborder="0" style="border:0"
                          src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY&q=ADDRESS&zoom=15">
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
.modalDialog,
.modalDialog > iframe{
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2.5% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #333;
}
```

The difference between this modal dialog and bootstrap's is the CSS simply sets the opacity to 0 (completely invisible) as opposed to hiding the div entirely.  When it's the target, it sets the opacity to 1.

If you notice, my close anchor tag links to: "#calendar"...  if you simply link to "#" it will bring you back to the top of the page.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the iframe into the modal after load and then apply styling via CSS.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal .modal-body').html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyAb9sz-Ih7YtVpdvoT5mLqgkJBx99yR8bc&origin=Anand,+Gujarat,+India&destination=Ahmedabad,+Gujarat,+India&mode=driving" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>');
});
```

In my case I needed the frame to be 100% height & width and this worked nicely :)